# Table won't stay anchored in two colums article

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I'm trying to put a table placed in the two columns of an article. This I can do. The problem is it won't stay in the middle of the text.

Here is my code,

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}

\section{Before you start}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rccc|ccc}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Model 1} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model2} \\
\hline
\hline
$SE(\%)$  & $60$ & $60$ & $60$ & $60$ & $60$ & $60$ \\
$SP(\%)$    & $70$ &  $70$ & $70$& $70$ &  $70$ & $70$ \\
$Gmean(\%)$ & $80$ & $80$ & $80$ & $80$ & $80$ & $80$ 
\label{tab:fO}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\FloatBarrier

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

and this is the result,

[image]

[image]

I would like the table to be in the middle of the text.

Comment: Two-columns floats can either go on a page of their own (`p`) or on top of the page (`t`), `h` or `b` is simply ignored. You can find more details (much more, actually!) in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: In two-column mode, double-width floats of type `figure*` and `table*` in a document of class `article` must be placed at the *top* of a page.

Comment: You can use the flofram package to create a full width column in the middle of the page, if you really want to.